# CS107 Assignment file couldn't compile, missing expat.h and thread_107.h files

Tags: c, multithreading, expat-parser

I was auditing cs107 at stanford online

The problem I ran into is with assignment 6, when I type "make" in terminal, the error message pops up. Basically, I miss two header files, which I guess can be got from the pre-compiled .lib file. But somehow it just doesn't work.

Here's part of the original make file:

```
CFLAGS = -D_REENTRANT -g -Wall -D__ostype_is_$(OSTYPE)__ -std=gnu99 -I/usr/class/cs107/include/ -Wno-unused-function $(DFLAG)
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/class/cs107/assignments/assn-6-rss-news-search-lib/$(OSTYPE) -L/usr/class/cs107/lib -lexpat -lrssnews $(PLATFORM_LIBS) $(THREAD_LIBS)
PFLAGS= -linker=/usr/pubsw/bin/ld -best-effort -threads=yes -max-threads=1000
```

Edit:

When I said "This is supposed to compile even without threading implementation", I meant that it should compile without FURTHER threading implementation by students.

So here's the error message with thread:

```
gcc -D_REENTRANT -g -Wall -D__ostype_is_linux__ -std=gnu99 -I/usr/class/cs107/include/ -Wno-unused-function -c -o rss-news-search.o rss-news-search.c
rss-news-search.c: In function ‘main’:
rss-news-search.c:109:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘InitThreadPackage’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
gcc rss-news-search.o -D_REENTRANT -g -Wall -D__ostype_is_linux__ -std=gnu99 -I/usr/class/cs107/include/ -Wno-unused-function -L/home/h/cs107/assn-6-rss-news-search-lib/linux -L/usr/class/cs107/lib -L. -lexpat -lrssnews -lnsl -lpthread -lthread_107_linux -o rss-news-search
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lthread_107_linux
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rss-news-search] Error 1
```

here's the error message without $(THREAD_LIBS):

```
gcc -D_REENTRANT -g -Wall -D__ostype_is_linux__ -std=gnu99 -I/usr/class/cs107/include/ -Wno-unused-function -c -o rss-news-search.o rss-news-search.c
rss-news-search.c: In function ‘main’:
rss-news-search.c:109:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘InitThreadPackage’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
gcc rss-news-search.o -D_REENTRANT -g -Wall -D__ostype_is_linux__ -std=gnu99 -I/usr/class/cs107/include/ -Wno-unused-function -L/home/h/cs107/assn-6-rss-news-search-lib/linux -L/usr/class/cs107/lib -L. -lexpat -lrssnews -lnsl -lpthread  -o rss-news-search
rss-news-search.o: In function `main':
/home/h/cs107/assn-6-rss-news-search/rss-news-search.c:109: undefined reference to `InitThreadPackage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rss-news-search] Error 1
```

In the later case, if I comment out "InitThreadPackage", it compiles just fine.

Comment: Post the makefile, or some links to the assignment resources. We don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. The assignment file can be found here http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icsppcs107/assignments.aspx which include a make file. It's Assignment 6.

Comment: Thanks and the link is this : http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/assn-6-rss-news-search.zip?

Comment: Yes. That one contains a make file. And the one right below it has the .lib files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the procedure to compile your project:

1. Create a file `assn-6-rss-news-search/thread_107.h`, and put this inside:

   `/* Empty header file */`
2. **Copy** the library `librssnews.a` from `assn-6-rss-news-search-lib/linux/` to `assn-6-rss-news-search/`
3. Modify the file `rss-news-search.c` by **commenting** the call to the function : `InitThreadPackage` on line **109**:

   //InitThreadPackage(false);
4. Modify the `Makefile` to include the **path to the current directory** (to be able to link to the library you've copied earlier `librssnews.a`):

The line **27** should look like this:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/class/cs107/assignments/assn-6-rss-news-search-lib/$(OSTYPE) -L/usr/class/cs107/lib -L. -lexpat -lrssnews $(PLATFORM_LIBS) $(THREAD_LIBS)
```

Then:

```
make clean
make
```

EDIT :

When you got this error `cannot find lthread_107_linux`, Edit your Makefile to remove this `$(THREAD_LIBS)` on line **27**:

```
LDFLAGS = -L/usr/class/cs107/assignments/assn-6-rss-news-search-lib/$(OSTYPE) -L/usr/class/cs107/lib -L. -lexpat -lrssnews $(PLATFORM_LIBS)
```

Comment: Now it prompts "cannot find lexpat" and "cannot find lthread_107_linux".

Comment: As Karl said if you are on Ubuntu install libexpat (sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev)

Comment: Cheers~~The first one is gone~~~ One more to go~~YEAH!

Comment: Thanks, it's gone too. But once I brings back InitThreadPackage on line 109 in rss-news-search.c. Another one comes up that says it's undefined. The assignment 6 is all about multithreading. Without $(THREAD_LIBS), the whole assignment wouldn't be accomplished.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand! We talk here about assn-6-rss-news-search, and there is no threading inside except the line 109 and i tell you to comment it. Are you trying another project or what?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make this clear before. The goal of that assignment is to build a Multithreaded RSS News Aggregator. rss-news-search.c is the starter code for students. This is supposed to compile even without threading implementation.

Comment: YES, IT COMPILE ON MY MACHINE! PLEASE POST YOUR ERRORS HERE (BY EDITING YOUR POST)

Answer (score 1):

The class-specific header files, like `thread_107.h` are found in `/usr/class/cs107/include/` on whatever machine the instructor is expecting the students to use.  If you're not using that machine, you'll have to copy those include files or make your own.

The `expat.h` file is from an open source library.  You'll need to install the appropriate package on the system you're compiling on.  On Ubuntu, that's `sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev`, but the package name should be similar on other distributions.

Comment: Thank you! Karl. I think I can get the expat.h. But how do I make my own thread_107.h? I'm sorry I am still new to cs.

Comment: You just make a file with that name, and when the compiler complains about unknown functions, you put a matching function declaration in there.